# Bootstrap table pagination and searching is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am new to bootstrap and working in D3.js, crossfilter.js to generate the table contents. I like to get the dataTable as in the following [URL](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) with some pagination and searching with in the datatable using bootstrap.

In that example the table is statically defined with id and class. I am able to run the html page with the desired output as in the example page source code.

But in my case I am generating a table from function and not able to get the pagination and searchBox on top of the table. I added all the supported files such as js and css files.

Here is my code and I just reduced the code to avoid more spaces in this portal.  May I know where I am doing mistake.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>DataTables example - Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/380cb78f450/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/380cb78f450/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.10.0/d3.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="crossfilter.js"></script>
    <div id="Default"  class="default"></div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable();
    $('#Default').show();
    });
    d3.json("myJson.json", function (desing) {
    var data = desing;
    var ndx = crossfilter(data);
    var state1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.region;});
    var dist1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.cluster;});
    var taluk1 = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.center;});
    var village1 =  ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.loan_type_id;});

    cfds = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.region; });
    $("#Default").html(totable(cfds.top(Infinity)));
    cfds.filterAll();  
    });

    function totable(json) {
    var html = "";
    html += "<thead>"
    html += "<tr>"
    html += "<th>REGION</th>"
    html += "<th>CLUSTER</th>"
    html += "<th>CENTER</th>"     
    html += "<th>GLP MONTH</th>"
    html += "<th>LOAN AMT DISBURSED</th>"
    html += "<th>NEW MEMBERS</th>"
    html += "<th>DEMAND</th>"
    html += "<th>PRINCIPAL</th>"
    html += "<th>INTEREST</th>"
    html += "<th>WRITTEN OFF</th>"
    html += "<th>HM-PROCESSED</th>"
    html += "<th>HM-ELIGIBLE</th>"
    html += "<th>Eligible %</th>"
    html += "<th>LOAN TYPE</th>"
    html += "</tr>"
    html += "</thead>"

    json.forEach(function (row) {
    html += "<tr role='row'>";
    for (key in row) {
    html += "<td>" + row[key] + "</td>";
    };
    html += "</tr>";
    });
    return "<table id='example' class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing='0' width='100%' role='grid' aria-describedby='example_info'>" + html + "</table>";
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does any jquer or bootstrap experts here to answer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working after I put the supported js files has been defined upon the end of the body tag.Also I initiate the dataTable under d3 function. All goes well now.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope its useful for someone..

Comment: Its working in firefox but not in chrome, Does anybody know solution for this problem?

Comment: Its not generating the datatable while changing the dropdown.. Onthe page loading dataTable works..